# Why Can't JSP 2.0 Tag Files Have Body-Content of "JSP"?

Tags: jsp, tags, jsp-tags

The "new" JSP 2.0 tag file tags are incredibly useful, and for most cases (at least that I've seen) they provide a far more readable format than a Java class.  However, while tag files can do *almost* everything a Java class tag can do, there is one giant thing they can't do: have "scripting" body content (ie. "<%" stuff between the start and end tags).

So, my question is multi-part:

1. Does anyone know why (from a design standpoint) this is?  Is it inherently impossible for tag files to have such content due to the way they are implemented or something?
2. Does anyone know if there are any future plans to allow for body-content="JSP" in tag files (in a future version of the JSP standard maybe)?
3. Does anyone know of any way to "hack" tag files to allow them to have scripting content (like by having a body-content of scriptless, and then processing the contents somehow)?

Basically my dream is to someday write tag files which don't result in exceptions if someone puts a

`<%= myVar %>`

inside, and I'm just trying to determine whether that dream is hopeless or not.

Comment: I guess another way to phrase this question is:

Why can't tag-file tags create non-simple ("classic") tags (is there some technical limitation)?

Is there any way at all (even if it requires resorting to "hacks") to create a "classic" tag using tag files?

Comment: The problem with all the responses saying "just avoid scripting in your JSPs", is that our entire application (seven years of code) is built on JSPs with scripting (and classes too of course, but there is no clear model/view/controller separation).  So unfortunately I can't just throw everything we already have written out the window.  This leaves me with a choice: develop all new tags using classes (*wince*) or find some way to use tag files on our existing pages ... and this Stack Overflow query is my way of trying to figure out how to do the latter.

Comment: Also, just to clarify, if there really is no way possible to have tag file tags with scripting inside, I'll award the bounty on this question to whoever provides the best explanation of why there is no way possible.  But I'm *really* hoping that someone has come up with a way (again, even if it requires a "hacky" solution like setting the body-content to "tagdependant" and then feeding that content back through the servlet somehow).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The JSP tags were designed this way so that there will be a complete separation of concerns between the presentation layer and the code behind. JSP pages are supposed to be edited by designers and therefore using Java code isn't appropriate.

I suppose that you need to adapt your coding habits in this philosophy. You can move all your Java code to your beans. Do whatever is required there and then pass the appropriate bean to the JSP page. Exception handling should also go there. If this isn't enough, you can always create your own tags to use.

Answer (score 2):

They can, if you're using old style tags, i.e. derived from BodyTag.  SimpleTag implementations can't however.

> Because JSP fragments do not support scriptlets, the  of a **SimpleTag** cannot be "JSP"

Personally I'd avoid using Java to write tags at all if you can, and just use the new .tag style.  You can incorporate Java code into such tag files, though in general if you are forced to do that you're probably doing something wrong.

Comment: "They can, if you're using old style tags"
Heh, I know; that's why I know about body-content JSP at all :-) But I'd like to achieve similar functionality using tag files; as you noted they are a much better mechanism for creating tags than Java classes.

As for "doing something wrong" because I have JSP content in my JSPs ... I don't follow.  ELScript and JSTL can do some stuff, but not everything.  Moreover, I'm stuck with tons of legacy pages that use scripting, so even if I could re-do everything without scripting bits ... I can't, because it would take way too long.

Comment: I know that this is an old thread, I was digging JSP tags questions... but in a situation like this, why upgrade? You could have stick to the old JSP format, or there were other requirements?

Answer (score 1):

In response to part 3, I've been able to find a hacky way of allowing tag files to have scripting content. You'll need three files: two jsp files and a tag file.

page.jsp

```html
<%@ taglib tagdir='/WEB-INF/tags' prefix='t' %>

<t:site page="page-content.jsp"></t:site>
```

site.tag:

```html
<%@ attribute name="page" required="true" %>

<html>
<body>
  <jsp:include page="${page}" />
</body>
</html>
```

page-content.jsp

```html
<!-- Insert all scripts here -->
```

PS. I've just inherited a super old website that sounds similar to what you've run into. It's probably best to not have any scriptlets, but this might be an okay step towards decoupling a legacy application where that's not an option.

PPS. Make sure that your web.xml declares the servlet version as 2.4+ or the tag file won't interpret `${page}`. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12146247/java-web-app-what-determines-my-servlet-api-version-does-it-get-specified-in).